# Qual framework recomendam para realização de testes unitários em javascript (ECMAScript 6)?

Tags: javascript, testes-de-unidade, tdd, ecmascript-6

Irei desenvolver uma aplicação web, utilizando ECMAScript 6.
Gostaria de seguir com a Técnica do TDD.
Qual framework recomendam para realização de testes unitários em javascript (ECMAScript  6)?

Comment: Depende do que queres fazer. Eu sugiro o Jest, do Facebook especificamente pelo suporte ES6 que tem. Mas como disse depende do que precisas testar. Acho a pergunta meio fora de escopo.

Comment: Olá Sérgio, obrigado pela resposta.
Irei desenvolver uma aplicação web, utilizando ECMAScript 6.
Gostaria de seguir com a Técnica do TDD e queria saber qual framework é recomendado para a adoção do teste unitário.

Comment: Creio que o Framework para teste unitário não dependa do ES6, mas sim do motor que vai interpretar os scripts/tests, provavelmente os testes rodam em um servidor com Node.js, sendo assim o Node.js vai suportar ES5 e 6 paralelamente sem problemas, então qualquer teste pode ser escrito em ES6 desde que vc siga a documentação do framework de maneira correta.

Comment: Use o Jest e sua vida será uma maravilha. https://facebook.github.io/jest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é o tipo da pergunta subjetiva que pode ter varias respostas, também subjetivas, visto que é o tipo de pergunta que pode gerar respostas baseadas em opiniões. Vou indicar 3 com citações de seus desenvolvedores. Na minha opinião, embora todos tenha qualidade, a escolha vai depender do contexto, mas existem outras opções que devem ser muito boas, tais como [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html) ou [Protactor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/), ambos desenvolvidos pelo time do Angular, e muitos outros, cada um com suas particularidade e especificidades.

### [Jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine)

> Jasmine é framework de testes para código Javascript, não depende de outros frameworks JS. Não requer DOM

### [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/)

> Poderoso unit testing javascritp framework, fácil de usar. É utilizado pelos projetos JQuery. JQuery UI e JQuery Mobile e é capaz de testar qualquer codigo generico JS, incluindo o o próprio projeto.

### [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/)

> Framework de testes javascript, standalone, não depende de outros frameworks.